# Using Foreach to print the values

Tags: php, json

> Stored JSON decoded data in a variable that variable array of data I need to print that I tried below code but I get a result in that one bug called see below image.
>   [image: php foreach code]

[image: result]

Comment: Why are you using `json_encode` inside php itself?

Comment: i am tried json_decode also

Comment: Why not simply work with `$packs`?

Comment: that is also not work

Comment: it seems you are using unnecessary json_encode. Give a shot without `json_encode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try writing

```
$pack = json_encode($packs,true);
```

out of echo, just below

```
$packs=data['packs'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$no = 1;
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($findCustomer,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){  
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$no.'</td>
            <td>'.$data['NAME'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['PHONE'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['STB_NUMBER'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['VC_NUMBER'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['agent_name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['created_on'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>';
                $array =$data['packs'];
                $pack = json_decode($array,true);
                foreach ($pack as $value) {
                    echo 'Pack-Name:'.$value['pack_dsc']."<br>Pack-Amount:".$value['pack_base_prc']."<br>";
                }
      echo '</td>
        </tr>';
    $no++;
}
```